# vb.net task.delay locks browser

Tags: vb.net, async-await

I am trying to do a very simple job in vb.net 4.5 framework; Create and run a simple Async Task that will symbolize (making several database calls asynchrnously/ parallel).

I am using vs2012 and vb.net  Very simple MVC app and one control.

The code is simple>

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Dim newTask As Task(Of String) = TryPause()
    lblResults2.Text = newTask.Result
End Sub

Public Async Function TryPause() As Task(Of String)
    Await Task.Delay(100)
    Return "hello World"
End Function
```

Code runs fine when the "task.delay" is remarked out.
But if it stays inside of the code, the Browser locks up.

Notice: thread.sleep works fine....

What am i missing?

Comment: You should never use `.Result` to synchronously wait for a `Task`.  This causes a deadlock that breaks your code.

Comment: thanks I will keep this in mind;  I am currently trying to run several processes in parallel and return the results back to the main caller;  I have been successful with the taskfactory symbolizing thread.sleep;  But I can not get task.delay to work,  it almost appears to be going to a background thread and never coming back to the caller.  I am trying this in webforms/mvc.  I am about to move away from proving the delay and just start making the Real database calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @SLaks correctly pointed out, the `Result` is causing a deadlock. I explain this in more detail [on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) and [in a recent MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx).